# No classes found in classes folder inside war

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, war

I converted my eclipse project to maven by creating a pom.xml file. I built the .war file by maven build command by specifying the goal

```
 clean compile install
```

and it build successfully. Now when I am running it on appache tomcate it throws no class found exceptions as I check  .war/WEB-INF/classes folder is empty. Why classes folder is empty? Is this the reason why .war is not running on apache.

Please let me know if you need any further details

Pom.xml

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>mycom</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>com</name>
<description>Maven project</description>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>terracotta-repository</id>
        <url>http://repo.terracotta.org/maven2</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>rome</groupId>
        <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mybaties -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-generator-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--Joda time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--java image scaling -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mortennobel</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-image-scaling</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mysql connector -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>Codehaus Snapshots</id>
        <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <finalName>jemm.organise.net</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/myproject</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                 <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What is value of `<warSourceDirectory>` in `pom.xml`?

Comment: At least part of the problem is that your `webXml` uses the wrong path separator. Are you getting any errors from the Maven run?

Comment: Vinay I post my pom file.

Comment: No error chrylis it was build successfully.

Comment: Show us your directory structure. Where are your sources placed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very hard to know the exact problem with so few details, however my guess would be that you have the wrong directory structure.  Your code must be in the `src/main/java/packagepath` directory otherwise maven will not be able to find it and will create an empty jar/war.

As an additional note, the `compile` phase is included when you invoke the `install` phase so you do not need to explicitly call it.

Comment: Hi Aurand,you are right my folder structure is not correct.So can I change my existing folder structure or I need to create a new project as I tried to create main/java inside my src but eclipse create it as package is there a way to create folder in eclipse

Comment: Right Click > New > Folder

Comment: Or just move things around directly in the file system and let eclipse figure it out afterwards.

Comment: when I right click it does not allows me to create folder inside src It creates the folder inside the project

Comment: when I right click on project and go to build path there it shows src/java/main (missing)

Comment: my problem was with java version. I had 1.8.101 and had to update to 1.8.144, then maven could recognize sources files at src/main/java